# Maximal nodes in a path with listeners or queries in firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, limit

In the firebase documentation for the realtime database limits you can find this statement:

> Total nodes in a path with listeners or queries on it:    75 million
>
> You can't listen to or query paths with more than 75 million nodes,
>   cumulative. However, you can still listen to or query child nodes. Try
>   drilling down deeper into the path or creating separate listeners or
>   queries for more specific portions of the path.

If I have a db model like this with 75 million entries (users) ...

```
{ 
     users : {
      uid1 : {age: 34, name: 'Tommy', links:{...} },
      uid2 : {age: 78, name: 'Mikel', links:{...} },
      uid3 : {age: 25, name: 'Chris', links:{...} },
      ...
      uid75000000 : {age: 33, name: 'Sam', links:{...} },
}
```

... and I add one new User to the list. Does the limit statement mean:

- Listeners on `users` like `onWrite()` stop working?
- Queries to the `users` path like `usersRef.orderByChild("age").limitToLast(20)` stop working?

**And what is the meaning of cumulative here?** Does the number 75 million include sub child nodes of the child nodes of the path node? Why using the word cumulative otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I believe every key is a node as firebase realtime database is stored as JSON object.

Firebase database allows up to 32 sub-nodes!

I don't think having 1 billion object in one list is ideal and I don't think this database is made for that! You might need to consider a different structure or [sharding your data](https://firebase.google.cn/docs/database/usage/sharding?hl=en-gb).

I'm not sure about the ability of the onWrite() function, but in general a user would be listening to a sub-node of the users list, so won't have a problem.

Listing to the whole tree would probably be useless, but users would be different.

Querying a large list will take for ever and would be costly if it works! Again, please, consider [sharding your data](https://firebase.google.cn/docs/database/usage/sharding?hl=en-gb).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. There is no limit to the breadth of the database, even though there is a limit of 32 depth. The unclear wording in the limits language raises the question, can I listed to a single node in that list even though it is one of 1B siblings? Obviously it seems that listening to the parent falls under the wording of the limit. Sharding data is only necessary of concurrent connections approach the 100k limit, so I do not believe sharding in this case would be necessary. I think I should be able to do what I want based on the wording, but I'd like it to be clear. Thanks

Comment: "can I listed to a single node in that list even though it is one of 1B siblings"
Correct, you can listen to a single node of that large list as long the children of this node don't exceed the limits.

Comment: "There is no limit to the breadth of the database"
Right, but querying this list would be slow as I heard from others who tried a while back!

Comment: "Sharding data is only necessary of concurrent connections approach the 100k limit"
Correct, but also useful to avoid other limits such as how many writes and reads per second